# authentication from json api on Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise, passwords, restful-authentication

I use devise and rails app for authenticate users from mobile; so the user sign up/sign in/ sign out from their mobile devices, the problem is for (sign up/sign in) so that the user send his plain text password over the wire, how can I encrypt the plain text password and decrypt it on the server side? I am very new to RoR and Devise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish when you say "send plaint text password over wire" but below [1] is a good tutorial for creating a json api with devise. It uses the old token_authenticable module which has been removed from devise so follow this gist [2] to make modifications.

[1]http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/

[2]https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6

Comment: I am checking your suggestion, but as I read other posts It would be a good idea to use SSL and HTTPS

Comment: also I find this which is very helpful http://thecodingdoc.com/blog/29/4/2013/authenticate-with-devise-and-afnetworking